# Why do particles on a string copy the motion of the particle behind it in wave motion?

Tags: waves

This is probably a stupid question

If I have a wave on string with wave velocity in a particular direction, each particle on that string "copies" the motion of the particle behind it. I have read about why do waves travel on a string
(https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/648999/354629). But I can't understand how can a particle only copy the motion of the particle just near to it from one direction, why doesn't it get affected by particles adjacent to it from both sides?

Comment: I think this hes to due to the 'backward wave' see https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-99049-7